# Ad Management for ASP.NET sites

Tags: asp.net, ads

I am looking out for an ad management software that will help me host ads on my website. I have checked out BanManPro but its way too costly. Google Ad manager has issues and the support system is not very active at the moment.

Has anyone create an ad management software open source that can be used on ASP.NET sites.

I am ready to purchase if the solution does not cost much.

Thanks for the answers in advance

Answer (score 1):

stackoverflow just implemented [BanManPro](http://www.banmanpro.com/default.asp) for their ads

Comment: Can OpenX be used on ASP.NET sites?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider

http://www.xigla.com/absolutebmnet/index.htm

its about 200$ for a single site

Comment: Have you used it? I saw that in Google search but features were not very impressive..